# Customize grep output

Tags: shell-script

I have a file named DeployList.txt and it contains sample lines as below.

```
Database/test.sql
Tivoli/jobstr01.js
Tivoli/res01.res
Tivoli/job01.job
Datastage/test.dsx
```

I need to grep lines starting with "Tivoli/", but I would need the .res lines first, followed by the .job and finally the .js lines. Any other pattern would follow subsequently . So the output would look like...

```
Tivoli/res01.res
Tivoli/job01.job
Tivoli/jobstr01.js
```

So I am stuck till..

```
grep -e ^Tivoli/ DeployList.txt
```

And I don't want to create any further temporary files for this purpose.

Comment: what "other pattern" is involved here? do you mean 'Tivoli/somethingelse.extension"? or something besides "Tivoli"?

Comment: Is a perl answer acceptable?

Comment: I think a perl/awk script is more suitable for this kind of task.

Comment: @JeffSchaller : Yes. If there's a chance that Tivoli/somethingelse.extension exists, it should come last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, in GNU Awk > 4.0

```
gawk -F'[.]' '
  BEGIN{
    i["res"]=3; i["job"]=2; i["js"]=1; 
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
  } 
  /^Tivoli/ {
    a[$0]=i[$2]
  } 
  END{
    for (x in a) print x
}' DeployList.txt 
Tivoli/res01.res
Tivoli/job01.job
Tivoli/jobstr01.js
```

The associative array `i["res"]=3; i["job"]=2; i["js"]=1` defines a sort order for the extensions - other extensions will return `0` so will sort last.